# use checkbox to lock textbox and keep value

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a vba userform for data entry into Excel 2010.
One textbox is for inputting country codes. I want to use a checkbox to allow
the user to lock this textbox after typing in the country so they can continue to enter data without having to type the country code again and again.

My previous attempt was to check if checkbox was checked and just set the focus on the textbox next to it.

```
if checkbox.value = true then
Me.txHome.setFocus
else ws.Cells(newRow,5).Value = Me.txCountry.Value
endif
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set up a public variable and use the checkbox change event to assign its value like so:

```
Public String myCountry

Sub CheckBox1_Change()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        myCountry = txCountry.Value
    End If

    txCountry.Locked = (CheckBox1.Value = True)    
End Sub
```

Then in your existing code, just use:

```
ws.Cells(newRow, 5).Value = myCountry
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When checkbox is unchecked no value is added to the excel sheet.